# How to monitor a iFrame?

Tags: javascript, iframe

After sending a iFrame on its way, i would like to know if there's a way to monitor it. Specifically i would like to know if the address informed in the `src` parameter replied with a 2xx, 3xx, 4xx or 5xx...

Address I'm pointing to is 100% dynamic, defined by a system administrator and is probably a internal web app...

I need to do this, because in case a 3xx or 5xx happens I must remove the iFrame and display a pre-defined error msg.

So, is there a way to intercept/overhear the replies that a iFrame will receive?

Comment: Can you effectively test the url that is provided to the src parameter with an ajax request? This would allow you to either go forward with the iframe or display your error message

Comment: @TravisJ no i can't because the url might trigger operations such as document check-out and others, and the probability of the implementation be idempotent is almost zero...